Why does python not find regex that regex101 does?
I have this regex, which works perfectly in regex101, but will not work in actual python. The find string exists in the test string, but python will not find it.
find_str = r'^([\s\S]*)(?<=\n\n)([ \n-]+Once in a Lifetime Values[ \n-]+?)(?=  if)([\s\S]+)$'
logging.info(f'Checking for existence....\n -- {re.search(find_str, text)}\n'

This produces a fail:
2024-05-29 16:05:23: INFO - Checking for existence....
  -- None

Any help?

Please add text to your code snippet.

Aside: You can use . instead of [\s\S] if you use flags=re.DOTALL

Might be as simple as the difference between \n and \r\n.

Gives a match, doesn't it.

fyi, there is a code generation option on the page you provided that you say the regex works at.  might grab that code and play with it....

Your code works fine. I'd add a few minor changes, such as the m flag for multiline, and \s+\bif\b instead of   if:
import re

text = """


  -----------------------------------------------
  ----------------- Runtime -----------------
  -----------------------------------------------

  -----------------------------------------------

  -----------------------------------------------
  ---------- Once in a Lifetime Values ----------
  -----------------------------------------------
  if someStuff ~= 2 then
      -- Specific Unit Configuration --
      someJunk
  end
 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------- END FILE --------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

"""
find_str = r'(?m)^([\s\S]*)(?<=\n\n)([\s\r\n-]+Once in a Lifetime Values[\s\r\n-]+?)(?=\s+if)([\s\S]+)$'
f = re.findall(find_str, text)[0]

for s in f:
    print(s)



Prints


  -----------------------------------------------
  ----------------- Runtime -----------------
  -----------------------------------------------

  -----------------------------------------------


  -----------------------------------------------
  ---------- Once in a Lifetime Values ----------
  -----------------------------------------------

  if someStuff ~= 2 then
      -- Specific Unit Configuration --
      someJunk
  end
 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------- END FILE --------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------


